# Statement and Proof of Deligne's Theorem

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, monoidal-categories

I am interested in Deligne's Theorem regarding how all tensor categories satisfying some "nice" properties are equivalent to $\textrm{Rep}(G, \epsilon)$ where $G$ is a supergroup. I have two questions.

1. What are precisely the "nice" properties of the tensor category that is assumed by Deligne's Theorem? In nLab and these lecture notes by [Etingof and Kannan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.04878.pdf) describe what these "nice" properties are and they seem to agree with each other. However, in this exposition by [Ostrik](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401347.pdf) on Deligne's original paper it states that the tensor category is further required to be finitely $\otimes$-generated (there exists some object $X$ such that every object in the category is a sub-summand of $X^{\otimes n}$ for some $n$). This assumption does not appear to be required based on the statement in nLab and notes by Etingof and Kannan. So I would like to confirm, is this additional assumption of being finitely $\otimes$-generated neccessary? I tried looking at the original paper by Deligne; however, it is in French and I couldn't find an English translation.
2. Can anyone recommend a source which provides a proof of Deligne's Theorem that is accessible to someone that is not very familiar with category theory? In particular, I have a "nice" tensor category and I am interested in trying to the supergroup $G$ such that the tensor category is equivalent to $\textrm{Rep}(G,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I should clarify better what I mean. I do have a working knowledge of category theory but I am by no means an expert in the area and haven't seriously gone through any journal articles on category theory before. I am just wondering if there exists a proof which avoids requiring any serious in-depth knowledge of category theory. Of course, if there isn't, then I will just need to roll up my sleeves and better learn category theory as you have suggested :).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for the advice. I have been reading parts of that book, so I guess I will start reading it in more detail. Though, correct me if I am wrong, that book doesn't have a proof of Deligne's theorem. Also, would you know the answer to my first question? Is the assumption that the category is finitely $\otimes$-generated required for Deligne's theorem?